# Spring remoting and restful urls

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a running application exposing services with Spring remoting HttpInvoker.

I have this definition in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
    <servlet class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The service exporter:

```
<bean name="/AccessMgtService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="employeeService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.xxx.service.EmployeeService"/>
</bean>
```

On the client side:

```
<bean id="remoteAccessService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://localhost:8180/HRManRemote/remoting/EmployeeService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.xxx.service.EmployeeService"/>
</bean>
```

I have now added a Restful service to my HRManRemote application.

I have a request mapping like this:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/rest/employees", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody List<Employee> getEmployees() {
...

}
```

I have an issue with the URL pattern. I can't figure out what url should be used to call the Rest service.

Neither http://localhost:8180/HRManRemote/remoting/rest/employees

nor http://localhost:8180/HRManRemote/rest/employees

work. The server tells me that no resource is defined for this url

What url do you think I should use?
Should I use a different request mapping?

Many thanks in advance

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

Edit your dispatcher servlet mapping as below :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And hit `http://localhost:8180/HRManRemote/rest/employees` from browser and also make sure scanning of `EmployeeController` in your spring configuration file.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it. But then, how should I call my HttpInvoker, since remoting comes from web.xml? Should I remove remoting from the HttpInvoker call?

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the following: http://localhost:8180/HRManRemote/remoting/AccessMgtService/rest/employees

I assume your site is named HRManRemote and you're bound to port 8180? If so, then remoting comes from web.xml, AccessMgtService from the bean configuration, and the rest from the Controller

Comment: I saw Arpit's answer come in around mind. Definitely make sure component scan is in your spring configuration so it picks this up.

Comment: Thanks. I will try both solutions and will let you know. In the url you propose, AccessMgtService is the name of the service called by the http invoker.